# How to change mail server for an IMAP account in OSX 10.11 when mail server greyed out?

Tags: mail.app, email, imap

I need to change the mail server for a IMAP account in OSX.

But the mail server field is greyed out (see below screenshot). Ideally i dont want to have to setup the account new from scratch a re download all the emails from the server.

Is there a way i can edit the mail server field of an existing IMAP account ?

[image: screenshot of mail settings]

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer after some searching via [HERE](http://guides.myonlinehelp.net/docs/comporium.net/macMailtp)

- Select the Advanced Tab, uncheck the box to “Automatically detect and maintain account settings”, save change.
- Go back into Preferences > Accounts, update the Incoming Mail Server to: mail.comporium.net